# datatypes dont match, correct query and table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-update

Got a new one for you, tried everything i could think of but without succes. 
I want to be able to edit some textboxes and then update their records in the database. I use this code:

```
 Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    connection.Open()
         cmdupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_stal SET Locatie = '" & cbLocatienummer.Text & "', Coordinaten = '" & txtCoordinaten.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & cbID.Text & "'"
    cmdupdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdupdate.Connection = connection
    cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("De gegevens zijn aangepast." & vbNewLine & "The data has been modified." & vbNewLine & "Die Daten sind angepasst.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Voersoorten")
    connection.Close()
    cmdupdate.Dispose()
```

I am certain that the names of the database table and it's fields are correct, tried using both numerical and textbased settings on the table fields(as normally they should be numerical, but they might be text too. ) 
However, when i load some data from the datagridvieuw into the textboxes, change the coordinates(for example) and hit the updatebutton, it will give me the error that the datatypes don't match. 
Apart from the above, what else can it be?

Comment: You should open the MS-Access database, look at the DATATYPE of the columns Locatie, Coordinate and ID, as you are writing them now they are all considered to be text fields but I bet that ID is numeric

Comment: Hello, Check the question, i already checked that, Only ID is numerical but is only used to identify the tablerow that needs changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write data to a database table using any kind of sql text you should NEVER use string concatenation to build the SQL. This because you could have problems in the string supplied (what if one of these strings contains an embedded single quote?) and because taking the user input and attaching it to your command is a really dangerous practice that leads to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)
(Well MS-Access doesn't support multiple commands so you are a bit safer here)

So you should rewrite your query in this way

```
Dim cmdText = "UPDATE tbl_stal SET Locatie = ?, Coordinaten = ? WHERE ID = ?"
Using connection = new OleDbConnection(.....)
Using cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection)
    connection.Open()
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbLocatienummer.Text)
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtCoordinaten.Text)
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToInt32(cbID.Text))
    cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Notice that you should provide a parameter with the exact datatype that matches the datatype of your field, strings for text fields, numbers for numeric fields.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I have not used this method before so forgive me for asking, but i pressume that the questionmarks should be changed to a @....? (So for example @locatie) so that it can be called in the cmdupdate statement? EDIT: Like in the second answer, didnt see that one yet...... AND it works. :) Thanks!

Comment: In OleDb the parameter placeholder is defined with the ?. When used with MS-Access though it is allowed to use also the @name form, probably for compatibility reasons with the big cousin named Sql Server. OleDb doesn't require an exact match between the parameter name and the parameter placeholder but you are required to add the parameters in the exact order in which the placeholder appears in text